# How can I return records with a MySQL query using a regular expression?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have records in my database that are searched with user input, and initially, this was sufficient for finding the correct records.

```
"SELECT id FROM plants WHERE Flower LIKE '%" . $sanitizedUserInput . "%'"
```

This was working all well and good, but then things started to happen like, searching 'red' was getting plants with the characters 'red' in sequence in their `Flower` field, and not simply the whole word 'red'.

I was suggested to simply put a space either side of the user's input, but I know this will fail where the word is the first word in the field, or the last. I thought to myself, I should use a regular expression! To search the word where it has a word boundary either side.

Unfortunately, I've never used regexs in a database before. How do you construct a query to search a db with a regex? Hopefully, it's as easy as this:

```
"SELECT id FROM plants WHERE Flower REGEX `/\b" . $sanitizedUserInput . " \b/`"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty much that easy.

[MySQL Reference Manual - Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

The word boundary sequences in MySQL regular expressions are `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` so you're going to end up with something like:

```
$query = "SELECT id ".
            "FROM plants ".
            "WHERE Flower REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$sanitizedUserInput."[[:>:]]'";
```

Comment: Really? I'm a pretty big fan of the mysql docs overall. The search function isn't great, but most pages are usually written pretty well, once I find the right one.

Comment: Yeah, I'm perhaps just a bit odd... the PHP or jQuery docs on the other hand... love 'em